# Why does the font size appear different for this question?

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro

I saw a question on the Newest Questions page (the 3rd question in the image below) whose title and body were rendered in a smaller font compared to other questions.

Here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2wEo.jpg

I reloaded the page several times, but it continued to appear like this. After a new question popped up in the feed, the font became normal.

So is the font change for questions intentional, or is it a bug? Or this is only happening to me? Because I have previously seen this font change several times as well.

> [Edit (1): Just to avoid a confusion  from comments below, the screenshot I have shared here is from phone (android , chrome-desktop mode).This is how I am seeing all the texts fonts (which is rendered normally in my device) :
>
> Page no (3) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMTlc.jpg
>
> Page no (2) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpPx0.jpg
>
> Page no (1) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cncl.jpg
>
> Eventhough those texts are larger compared to the view from other devices, they are uniform except the third question in problem screenshot.
>
> Edit (2) : I've replaced the screenshot image from the question by its image link, because when I viewed from PC, the image figure was showing comparatively larger in size, but the same screenshot looked normal when I viewed from my phone.]

Comment: The culprit seems to be the non-LaTeX mu in the title [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/700826/2451) (v2).

Comment: Looks like a bug in the text renderer to me. I've added a status-review tag which should summon an SE employee sooner or later to look at this. In general, questions that aren't specific to physics.SE get better responses at [meta.SE], but it's fine to post them here.

Comment: Do you have a userscript that's making the text larger than it would otherwise be? We're not able to reproduce this and the text size you have for the questions and body text is significantly larger than it appears on our devices. This is what I'm seeing for that exact same question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO9Wj.png

Comment: I've marked this as norepro because we can't reproduce this issue. If this was caused by a userscript, then there's not much we can do about it. :) If you can reproduce it without any scripts running, please [edit] your question to explain how and leave a comment for me (or have the mods re-status-review the question).

Comment: Hi @Catija. You're probably aware of this but just to eliminate a possible confusion in case you haven't noticed it: Note that OP refers to the previous v2 of Phys.SE q 700826; not the current.

Comment: @Qmechanic I don't have a way to check that what they're reporting is the case if the current version is OK. If y'all found a way to fix the question title so that this no longer is an issue, again, I don't see any reason for us to fix it if this happens extremely rarely - also, again, this user clearly has something making question titles bigger than they are supposed to be - I don't see any questions with MathJax titles that are sized improperly. If you're able to show me an example that is improperly sized when the page is rendered normally, I'm happy to investigate further.

Comment: @Mitra can you edit your question to include more details about your system (os, browser version, device, etc)? I've tried to reproduce even the giant size text in Chrome desktop view on my iPhone and I can't see that. The sizes all look correct. If you're on an Android, the behavior may be different. It's also possible you're on an older version of the browser than what we support (I know some older phones can't always be updated). I'm sorry but I'm just struggling to reproduce the issue and it's not clear to me that anyone else has.